# Scope issue inside React.createClass

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a scope issue that I'm struggling to solve.

I import getTrackNotes into the es6 module, and I want to reference it inside the React class as per the below, but this is set to the Track (React Class).

How can I reference it?

```
import { getTrackNotes } from '../utils/immutableInstruments';

const Track = React.createClass({

    componentDidMount() {

        const { trackId } = this.props.params;

        function updateTimeSequencer (socket, state, getTrackNotes, TimeSequencer, instruments, trackId)
        {

            //I want to call getTrackNotes here, but the scope is set to the Track React class
            **getTrackNotes();**

        }
        var instruments = this.props.instruments;

        socket.on('state', updateTimeSequencer.bind(this, socket));
     }
```

Answer (score 3):

Your `getTrackNotes` function would be inherited from the top scope, but you are overriding it with a same name function argument. Just remove `getTrackNotes` from the function arguments list or rename the argument to something else:

```js
function updateTimeSequencer (socket, state, thisIsSomethingElse, TimeSequencer, instruments, trackId)
```

Comment: Ah, I was wondering what the hell was going on, I'll try that thanks